# jquery conflict error while showing modal

Tags: javascript, php

[When loading the page i am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDOZp.png)

> Please help me out.. i am showing popup in another page its working
>   but i am doing same thing in another page the modal popup is opened
>   but showing error. that error i have mention in screenshot.

myform that i saved in modal.phtml

```
<div class="row text-right required-fields"><span>*</span> Required Fields </div>
<div class="reg-section1">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="results" class="form-group col-md-12 pl10 reg-ipad-pr0">    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pl0 reg-ipad-pr0">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pl0 reg-ipad-pr0">

            <input class="form-control" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" >                           
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pl0 reg-ipad-pr0">

            <input class="form-control" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" >                         
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12 pl0 reg-ipad-pr0">

            <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dateofBirth" id="dateofBirth" />
                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                  
</div>
<hr class="dotted-line">
<div class="row text-center ptb30">
    <input class="btn btn-default btn-info registration-save-btn" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Check" id="checkValues" />
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" id="reset" class="btn btn-default btn-info registration-cancel-btn">                     
</div>
```

button to hit the ajax

```
  <a class="yes" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitForopenmodal();">cancel</a>
```

Javascript code

```
function submitForopenmodal(url)
{


    $('#alertModalBox2').modal();
    $("#alertModalBox2 .modal-title").html('Submit Result For test');
    $("#alertModalBox2 .modal-body").html('Loading..');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: modal.phtml
        //dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data !== '')
            {

                var htmlcontent = data;

            } else {

                var htmlcontent = 'No information Found for this product ';
            }
            $("#alertModalBox2 .modal-body").html(htmlcontent);
            $('#alertModalBox2').addClass('in');
            $("#alertModalBox2").css("display", "block");
            $("#alertModalBox2 .modal-footer").html('');

             }
          });
  }
```

This is my modal where i want to show the text body from modal.phtml page.

```
<div id="alertModalBox2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog bulk-pricing-modal">


    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-cancel-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: have you included jquery and other required js libraries..

Comment: yes, that's why its working in another page.. i thing some conflict error..  TypeError: $(...).on is not a function ,$(...).formValidation is not a function, $(...).datepicker is not a function. these errors are comming

Comment: where is the error on your console?

Comment: do you declare jQuery correctly?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: t(...).on is not a function

Comment: so have u included jquery ui library?

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/fTcUzTCDSsGWo5LQylD35Q.png   please refer this link for my error.

Comment: Please refer to the below, same exact issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32065797/jquery-validation-uncaught-type-error-formvalidation-is-not-a-function

Comment: Check if you do not load more then one jQuery library at once

Comment: It's working in another page? That does not mean it will work on this page.

Comment: What should i do? i checked everything..